# Plot aspect changes with file size geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I trying to plot this

```
ggplot() +
      geom_rect(data = don7, aes(xmin = startPos , xmax = finalPos , ymin = 0, ymax = 1, fill=sv)) +
      geom_rect(data = don10, aes(xmin = startPos, xmax = finalPos , ymin = 1, ymax = 2, fill=sv)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green", "blue", "black"))+
      theme_bw() +
      theme( 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=20),
      )
```

where

```
> head(don7)
       chrteq  start    end  sv chr tot startPos finalPos
1 NC_045001.1  76169  76207 INS   3   0    76169    76207
2 NC_045001.1 211586 211615 INS   3   0   211586   211615
3 NC_045001.1 253399 253424 INS   3   0   253399   253424
4 NC_045001.1 260178 260299 DUP   3   0   260178   260299
5 NC_045001.1 323052 323156 DEL   3   0   323052   323156
6 NC_045001.1 348140 348180 DEL   3   0   348140   348180

> head(don10)
       chrteq  start    end  sv chr tot startPos finalPos
1 NC_045001.1  30695  30731 INS   3   0    30695    30731
2 NC_045001.1  91074  91155 INS   3   0    91074    91155
3 NC_045001.1 123627 123658 INS   3   0   123627   123658
4 NC_045001.1 158838 158923 DEL   3   0   158838   158923
5 NC_045001.1 177204 177231 DEL   3   0   177204   177231
6 NC_045001.1 212236 212878 DEL   3   0   212236   212878
```

but some rectangles are not shown, as depending how big I save the plot different rectangles show up/disappear

[image]

[image]

why is that?

thxs

EDIT: using pointed strategies
[image]

I noticed that bc I have much more DEL than INV, for example, the plot will look a lot red, in this case. I was wondering how I can grep only INS and plot from 0-1, DUP 1-2 and so on.

Comment: My guess is that its a plotting artefact when rectangles are thinner than a single pixel.  Some are around 30 wide, on a scale that spans 100 million.

Comment: I agree with dww and one thing you might consider given that your data doesn't cover the x-axis very densely, is to also specify `colour = sv`, so that every rectangle gets at least a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, if you plot this into a vector-based engine (e.g., pdf), you can see all of the lines:

```r
pdf("~/Downloads/5719890_66093693.pdf", height = 2)
# your plot code
dev.off()
```

[image: all the lines are seen]

Taking @teunbrand's suggestion, adding `colour=sv` gives some more break-out:

```r
ggplot() +
      geom_rect(data = don7, aes(xmin = startPos , xmax = finalPos , ymin = 0, ymax = 1, fill = sv, colour = sv)) +
      geom_rect(data = don10, aes(xmin = startPos, xmax = finalPos , ymin = 1, ymax = 2, fill = sv, colour = sv)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green", "blue", "black"))+
      theme_bw() +
      theme( 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=20),
      )
```

[image: raster plot showing all lines]

Comment: Got it. I noticed that using the approach you suggest bc I have much more DEL than INV, for example, the plot will look a lot red, in this case. I was thinking how I can grep only INS and plot from 0-1, DUP 1-2 and so on. Lmk if this should be considered an entirely new question. Thanks a lot!